# Evaluation of a series involving binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have a series $S$ I want to simplify, in terms of an integer $n$:

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+2}$$

I *think* that $$(n+2) {2n+2 \choose n+2} S = 1$$

which would mean $$S = \left[(n+2) {2n+2 \choose n+2} \right]^{-1}$$

but I'm stuck as to how to show this (if indeed it is true!).

Any help (even just with where to start) would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: your sum is given by $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 4^{-n-1} n!}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Sorry but why do you "think" this identity holds? Do you mean you were actually *given* the value of the sum and you are asking for a proof? 'Cause sincerely, unless the Goddess is speaking directly to you, how did you come to think this?

Comment: The series comes about when integrating a probability density( $p(x) = (n+2){2n+2 \choose n+2} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k e^{-(n+k+2)x}$ ) across it's entire sample space ( $x \in [0,\infty)$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+2}x^{n+k+2} $$
and then
$$ S'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^kx^{n+k+1}=x^{n+1}(1-x)^n. $$
So
$$ S=\int_0^1x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n}dx $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\frac12\left[\int_0^1x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n}dx+\int_0^1(1-x)^{n+1}x^{n}dx\right]\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^1(1-x)^nx^ndx=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx^{n+1}\\
&=&\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-1}x^{n+1}dx\\
&=&\frac{n(n-1)}{2(n+1)(n+2)}\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-2}nx^{n+2}dx\\
&=&\cdots\\
&=&\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{2(n+1)(n+2)\cdots2n}\int_0^1x^{2n+1}dx\\
&=&\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{2(n+1)(n+2)\cdots2n(2n+1)}\\
&=&\frac{(n!)^2}{2(2n+1)!}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Excellent, many thanks! I've just checked, and this answer is consistent with my suggested simplification above.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: Another way to evaluate the integral xpaul gives for the sum is to recognise it as a beta function. Here $$S = B(n + 2,n + 1) = \frac{\Gamma(n + 2) \Gamma (n + 1)}{\Gamma (2n + 3)} = \frac{(n + 1)! n!}{(2n + 2)!} = \frac{(n!)^2}{2(2n + 1)!}.$$